# MIPS how do you do a word to binary?

Tags: mips

I have a 1010(base 2) 4 bit bit vector and a 1010(base 10) word. I need to show that they are equal.

Comment: But they aren't equal, the base 2 is 10, the base 10 is 1010, what do you mean?

Comment: i actually have "1010" in a word and I need to convert it into binary so that it matches 10 in base 2.

Comment: Bitwise AND and OR can be used for extracting and inserting bits, and shift instructions can be used to move bits around. It's not clear from your question exactly what you're having trouble with.

Answer (score -1):

Not totally sure of what you are trying to do, is this what you are looking for?

```
// 1010(base10) = 0000 0011 1111 0010(base2) -> requires 16 bits

unsigned base2 = 10;        // 1010 in base 2
unsigned base10 = 1010;     // Assume only 1's and 0's are used
unsigned answer = 0;

int bit = 0;

for (int bit = 0; base10 > 0; bit++)
{
    if (base10 % 10) answer |= (0x01 << bit);
    base10 /= 10;
}

// At this point answer = 1010(base2)
```